# AWS CloudFormation errors when template gets AllocationID for AWS::EC2::EIP (Elastic IP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, elastic-ip

I've created a stack with an EIP resource and I'm trying to get the allocation ID and the CloudFormation validator keeps yelling at me. I extracted the EIP into a very simple stack where it's the only resource and I still can't get a valid template. Am I going crazy or AWS messing with me?? Below is the simple stack template that fails validation, and if I use it as a nested stack it fails on creation.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Create an EIP to be used by Alliance web proxy EC2 instance.
Resources:
  EIPForProxy:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
Outputs:
  EIPAllocationID:
    Value: !GetAtt EIPForProxy.AllocationID
  EIPPublicIP:
    Value: !Ref EIPForProxy
```

Comment: Can you add the error you get from Cloudformation?

Answer (score 0):

Being a VPC elastic IP addresse, you can only export that as a value and use this template as a sub-stack to your parent stack. You cannot output it as a value using GetAtt function.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Create an EIP to be used by Alliance web proxy EC2 instance.
Resources:
  EIPForProxy:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
Outputs:
  EIPAllocationID:
    Value: 'null'
    Export:
      Name: MyEIP::AllocationId
  EIPPublicIP:
    Value:
      Ref: EIPForProxy
```